# Infix to Postfix converter + evaluator program printing properly to console but improperly to text file

Tags: c++, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm working in Linux on an infix to postfix evaluator for my CSC class, and we have to pipe the output to a text file to compare to our instructor's output.

The problem is that my program is printing the proper output when I simply run it on the command line, but it prints seemingly random ASCII characters to the text file when I run `./a.out > output.txt`.  We have been doing assignments this way all Quarter, and this is the first time something like this has happened.

All my code is below, as I have no idea what the problem could be.

Please note, the `Stack` and `Queue` are of my own design from previous assignments, and use a `LinkedList` as underlying structure. These assignments have all worked perfectly, so I have no reason to believe they are the problem.  Also, the program is not entirely complete and does not account for parentheses yet, but has some logic in place already which will be necessary to do so.  This issue is really, really weird.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include "GenericList.cc"
#include "Stack.cc"
#include "Queue.cc"

using namespace std;

void clear(char[MAX_SIZE]);
Queue<char> infix_builder(char[MAX_SIZE]);
void post_builder(Queue<char>&);//builds the postfix queue
void next_char(Queue<char>&, char);//find the next character's place in the queue
double solution(Queue<char>&);//Solves the equation
bool notop(char);//returns true if the char is not an operator
bool priority(char, char);//returns true if char a has a higher priority than char b
int main()
{
char input[MAX_SIZE];

//erase all values contained by input
clear(input);

//main loop, read each line and process them, one at a time
while(cin.getline(input, MAX_SIZE))
{
    Queue<char> mainq = infix_builder(input);//create a queue from the input
    //cout << "Printing input: " << endl;
    cout << mainq << endl;

    post_builder(mainq);//create the postfix queue
    //cout << "Printing infixed: " << endl;
    cout << mainq << endl;

    cout << solution(mainq) << endl << endl;//solve the equation and print 

    //cleanup
    clear(input);
}
return 0;
}

//clear the char array
void clear(char input[MAX_SIZE])
{
//set all values of a char array of MAX_SIZE to spaces
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    input[i] = ' ';
}

//Create a queue from the input data
Queue<char> infix_builder(char input[MAX_SIZE])
{
Queue<char> q;
for(int i = 0; ((input[i] != ' ') && (i < MAX_SIZE)); i++)
    q.Enqueue(input[i]);
return q;
}

void post_builder(Queue<char> &q)
{
Queue<char> p;//The postfix queue
Queue<char> pq;//A prioritized queue of operators
//build a post-fixed queue
while(!q.IsEmpty())
{
    char next = q.Dequeue();
    if(notop(next))//if the character is not an operator
    {
        if(((next - '0') >= 0) && ((next - '0') <= 9))//filter out bad char
            p.Enqueue(next);
    }
    else if(next != '(')
    {
        if(pq.IsEmpty())//if it is empty
            pq.Enqueue(next);
        else if(priority(pq.Peek(), next))//if it is time to empty some
        {
            while(!pq.IsEmpty() && priority(pq.Peek(), next))
                p.Enqueue(pq.Dequeue());
            next_char(pq, next);
        }
        else
        {
            next_char(pq, next);
        };          
    }
}

//Empty the rest of the operators into the postfix queue
while(!pq.IsEmpty())
    p.Enqueue(pq.Dequeue());
q = p;
}

double solution(Queue<char>& q)//solves the equation and returns a floating point answr
{
double a;
double b;
Stack<double> stack;

while(!q.IsEmpty())
{
    char next = q.Dequeue();
    if(((next - '0') >= 0) && ((next - '0') <= 9))
        stack.Push((next - '0'));
    else if(next == '+')//perform operator +
    {
        a = stack.Pop();
        b = stack.Pop();
        b += a;
        stack.Push(b);
    }
    else if(next == '-')//perform operator -
    {
        a = stack.Pop();
        b = stack.Pop();
        b -= a;
        stack.Push(b);
    }
    else if(next == '*')//perform * operator
    {
        a = stack.Pop();
        b = stack.Pop();
        b *= a;
        stack.Push(b);
    }
    else if(next == '/')//perform / operator
    {
        a = stack.Pop();
        b = stack.Pop();
        b /= a;
        stack.Push(b);
    }
    else//perform ^ operation
    {
        a = stack.Pop();
        b = stack.Pop();
        stack.Push(pow(b, a));
    }   
}//end while, q is empty, stack.num_items == 1

return stack.Pop();//return the final value pushed onto the stack

}

void next_char(Queue<char>& pq, char next)
{
Queue<char> temp;
while(!pq.IsEmpty() && priority(pq.Peek(), next))/
    temp.Enqueue(pq.Dequeue());
temp.Enqueue(next);//insert next
while(!pq.IsEmpty())//finish copying the Queue
    temp.Enqueue(pq.Dequeue());
pq = temp;//set pq equal to the new queue
}

bool notop(char c)
{
return ((c != '+') && (c != '-') && (c != '*') && (c != '/') && (c != '^') && (c   != '(') && (c != ')'));
}

bool priority(char a, char b)
{
if((b == '+') || (b == '-'))
        return true;//a will always have priority if b is + or -
else if((b == '*') || (b == '/'))
    return ((a == '^') || (a == '*') || (a == '/'));// * and / are equal 
else
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you populate the infix queue, you look for spaces instead of using the cstring function "strlen(char[])".  This includes the \0 escape character your char array uses to denote the end in your queue.  This operator is then printed to the .txt file and gives you the strange characters to which you have referred.  Use strlen().